# IBM MobileFirst 8.0 WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken() No Response

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm previewing the MobileFirst app (Cordova) on both browser and iOS Emulator but there doesn't seem to be any response when I call `WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken()`.

I've tried to allow cross origin request but still face the same issue. Does anyone have any suggestions for what I should look at?

Comment: I would check : 1) is the server reachable? Check the config.xml.
2) Do you see the flow entering success/failure callbacks ? If so, what is the message there? 3) Check network traffic and see if the call is reaching the server and back.

Comment: did u find any solution?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue on the iOS emulator.  I even used Wireshark to see what was happening and the app never fired the authorisation request.

In the end I found that if you're running XCode 8.x, you have to enable keychain sharing by selecting the project -> Capabilities -> Keychain Sharing, and setting it to On.

After that I had to register the app again and all worked fine.

Make sure when you register or push the app and you're prompted for the version number, that you enter x.x.x instead of x.x - otherwise the server will not recognise the app.

Another thing to double check is the mfp:server runtime and url values in the config.xml file, if your pc's ip address has changed then the url value could be incorrect.